# How do I add an alias for magrittr pipe from R in vscode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I would like an alias for typing `%>%` in vscode (the pipe command in R) . In Rstudio this is mapped to ctrl + shift + M, but if this is not available in vscode for any reason I am happy to map to something else, I am just not sure how to add a new alias.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You only need to add this to your `keybindings.json` file (see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) to know how to open it):

```
{
  "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
  "command": "type",
  "args": { "text": " %>% " },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
}
```

This way you don't need macros

---

`keybindings.json` file after modification:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
        "command": "type",
        "args": { "text": " %>% " },
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
    }
]
```

If you are a Mac user and prefer RStudio's `Cmd+Shift+m` shortcut, set the above key line to `"key": "Cmd+Shift+m"`.

If you are new to VSCode, [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/how-to-add-r-magrittrs-pipe-operator-in-vscode-as-keyboard-shortcut/) is a helpful how-to video.

Comment: I'd suggest to add `"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"`

Comment: @Mossa Nice! I edited the answer to add this, thanks!

Comment: How about multiple langIds? Specifically r and Rmd.

Answer (score 11):

You can also add it to rmd in the following way

```
{
  "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
  "command": "type",
  "args": { "text": " %>% " },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == rmd"
}
```

and to the R terminal in the following way

```
    {
      "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " },
      "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
```

This is how my settings.json look to add %>% and <- to my Rmarkdowns, Rscripts and R terminal (including radian):

```
[
    // OTHER KEYBINDINGS,


 
    // keybindings for R scripts. 
    {
      "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
    },
    {
      "key": "Alt+-",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " <- " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
    },
    // keybindings for Rmarkdown
    {
      "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == rmd"
    },
    {
      "key": "Alt+-",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " <- " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == rmd"
    },
    // keybindings for R terminal (radian included)
    {
      "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " },
      "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
      "key": "Alt+-",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "args": { "text": " <- " },
      "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    // OTHER KEYBINDINGS

]
```

Comment: How can you add a new line after the use of pipe? " %>%newline"

Comment: for new line use `\n`, such as `"args": { "text": " %>%\n" },`

Comment: Btw way, one can use regex to match multiple languages, so you don't need to duplicate the commands for R and Rmd. Use `"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId =~ /r|rmd/"` instead.

Comment: `"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId =~ /r|rmd|quarto/"` will extend this to include Quarto.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use vscode, but perhaps a macro can work using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros. It says in the **Passing Arguments to Commands** section:

> Many commands accept arguments, like the "type" command which lets you insert text into the editor.

Perhaps this will work (untested). Add this to your `settings.json`:

```
"macros": {
  "addPipe": [
    "cursorEnd",
      {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "%>%"}}
  ]
}
```

and this to your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+M",
  "command": "macros.addPipe"
}
```